# How to define a select field in a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

What is the correct way to include a select field within a nested form in Rails 3.2?

I currently have

```
//IN THE PARENT FORM

<%= f.fields_for :crayons  do |crayon| %>
   <%= render 'caryon_fields', :f=>crayon %>
<% end %>

//IN THE PARTIAL

<div class="nested-fields">
   <%= select (:crayon, :color, [['Red',1],['Blue',2],['Yellow',3],['Green',4]] ) %>
</div>
```

This is not saving the selected value to the database. I assume this is because the builder  is not being passed.

How should I define a select field with hardcoded options in a nested field? Do I need to change tag, i.e. `select_tag` or `collection_select`. I'm still unsure of the differences between all these. If anyone can point me towards a clear description it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need associate to your form in your partial like that :

```
<div class="nested-fields">
   <%= f.select (:crayon, :color, [['Red',1],['Blue',2],['Yellow',3],['Green',4]] ) %>
</div>
```

Whitout partial it's :

```
<%= f.fields_for :crayons  do |crayon| %>
  <div class="nested-fields">
   <%= crayon.select (:crayon, :color, [['Red',1],['Blue',2],['Yellow',3],['Green',4]] ) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks shingara. I already tried that. It returns `undefined method "merge"`. I don't think this is the correct syntax. It would make more sense to have <%= select (f, :color, ...%>, wouldn't it? But that also doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, this turns out to be the solution, I was simply looking at it the wrong way round. `<%= f.select (:color, [["red',1].....%>`. I needed to remove the model reference, not replace it with the builder. Thanks for getting me thinking along another line.